# include a module unless the expectation's file is in a certain directory?

Tags: rspec

Let's say I have four spec files in my project:

```
spec/foo/foo_one_spec.rb
spec/foo/foo_two_spec.rb
spec/baz/baz_one_spec.rb
spec/baz/baz_two_spec.rb
```

How could I configure my spec file to include a certain module only if the current spec file is **not** inside the baz directory?

Here's some pseudo-code to illustrate:

```
module Moddy
    extend RSpec::SharedContext
    let(:message){ 'hello' }
    before{ puts message }
end

RSpec.configure do |c|
    # path is pseudo-code; pretending it returns the path of the current expectation
    c.include Moddy unless path.includes?('/baz/')
end
```

So, upon running my specs, I expect `'hello'` to be printed to the screen before every expectation except for those inside the files `baz_one_spec` and `baz_two_spec`.

If this isn't possible, could you show me how to achieve this with tags? All specs inside `baz` will have to be tagged, I accept this.

Comment: You could take a look at rspec-rails - it (optionally) does something very similar

Comment: Can I specify the directories? Or is it just `models`, `controllers` rather than `foo` or !`baz`?

Comment: I don't know - I was suggesting that you look at how rspec-rails does it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running with [Frederick Cheung's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33022300/include-a-module-unless-the-expectations-file-is-in-a-certain-directory#comment53870614_33022300), I figured out how to automatically define metadata for directories, then you can include the module conditionally with that metadata. This is based on how `rspec-rails` [infers spec type from file location](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/efe7c53c6a431a4a6d938b28361a7bb19c6860a4/lib/rspec/rails/configuration.rb#L84-L91).

I'm working with two trivial specs:

```rb
# spec/foo/foo_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'Foo' do
  it 'printed something before the test ran' do
    expect(1).to eq(1)
  end
end
```

```
# spec/bar/bar_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'Bar' do
  it 'did not print anything before the test ran' do
    expect(1).to eq(1)
  end
end
```

In `spec_helper`, I copied your `Moddy` and used [define_derived_metadata](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-core/RSpec%2FCore%2FConfiguration%3Adefine_derived_metadata) to tag files in `spec/foo`:

```rb
# spec/spec_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.define_derived_metadata(file_path: %r(spec/foo)) do |metadata|
    metadata[:include_moddy] = true
  end

  config.include Moddy, include_moddy: true
end
```

The `file_path` option accepts a regular expression to match and run the block for. This one accepts `spec/foo`, but yours could accept everything else, or you could make an expression for each in a list of directories like `rspec-rails` does with [`DIRECTORY_MAPPINGS`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/efe7c53c6a431a4a6d938b28361a7bb19c6860a4/lib/rspec/rails/configuration.rb#L27-L37).

After that, here's what the spec run looks like:

```
$ rspec

Bar
  did not print anything before the test ran

Foo
hello
  printed something before the test ran

Finished in 0.00101 seconds (files took 0.07205 seconds to load)
2 examples, 0 failures
```